# WIX Custom Action Execution failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, custom-action, wix3.7

I have created a setup to execute scripts on database. But when i tried to run the setup i have got the following error which i have fetched out from logs.

```
Doing action: VerifyConnection Action 12:03:17: VerifyConnection.  
Action start 12:03:17: VerifyConnection. MSI (c) (38:E0) 
[12:03:17:739]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\adityak\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI4F99.tmp, Entrypoint: VerifyConnection MSI (c) (38:A4) [12:03:17:741]: Cloaking enabled. MSI (c) (38:A4) 
[12:03:17:741]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server MSI (c) (38:A4) 
[12:03:17:742]: Connected to service for CA interface. MSI (c) (38:54) 
[12:03:17:788]: Note: 1: 1723 2: VerifyConnection 3: VerifyConnection 4: C:\Users\adityak\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI4F99.tmp  Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action VerifyConnection, entry: VerifyConnection, library: C:\Users\adityak\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI4F99.tmp  MSI (c) (38:54) 
[12:03:19:186]: Product: CRMnext -- Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action VerifyConnection, entry: VerifyConnection, library: C:\Users\adityak\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI4F99.tmp

Action ended 12:03:19: VerifyConnection. Return value 3.
DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action VerifyConnection failed
```

Any Idea how to resolve this issue???

Comment: According to the error message "A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run." Have you tried to find what DLL is mentioned here?

Comment: I am using a package of dlls using makeSFxCA.exe in post build events of my Custom Action Project . At the time when VerifyConnection action is called it might be possible that the dll it need is not available.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your action has the correct signature; especially the method needs to be "public" and "static", i.e. something along the lines of "public static ActionResult doSomething(Session session)"
2. Mark the mehtod with the "CustomAction" attribute, so it gets exported
3. When dealing with multiple custom actions implemented in one dll, make sure you are not running into a known MakeSfxCA bug (cf. http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4502/ or [Adding a new Custom Action to a project prevents an existing Custom Action from being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974539))